# Problem exporting RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm getting a weird error message trying to export an RCP application:

```
Error
Fri Jun 17 15:07:25 IDT 2011
 Missing requirement: My Application 1.0.0.201106171507 (myAppProductConf 1.0.0.201106171507) requires 'com.my.application.model.dynamicLoader [1.0.0.201106171507]' but it could not be found
```

Of course, I double checked and indeed the dynamicLoader module is present at the dependency list, and I also tried to enforce a constraint telling eclipse that the version has to be 1.0.0.qualifier.
Several solutions (looked up in google) suggested that the .product file should have a 1.0.0.qualifier version number instead of the default 0.0.0 ver. number, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions? something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Found the solution.
Changing the version of each plugin (manifest file) in my project from 1.0.0.qualifier to 1.0.0 solved the problem.

Going to file a bug on that.

Answer (score 2):

Our [product](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/e4/org.eclipse.e4.ui/examples/org.eclipse.e4.ui.examples.legacy.workbench/legacy-eclipse.product?view=markup) is feature based, but the same principle should apply.  Your product should have your plugin ids and for the version should have `version="0.0.0"`, or simply not specify the version at all ([contacts demo](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/e4/org.eclipse.e4.ui/examples/org.eclipse.e4.demo.contacts/contacts.product?view=markup)).  But not specifying the version, that allows the export to fill it in correctly when exporting the product.

It is a good practice to have `1.0.0.qualifier` in your plugin MANIFEST.MFs so that during development you can tell the difference between builds of your plugin.  Most of the eclipse framework will treat all plugins with `1.0.0` as if they have the same content, even if they do not.

PW